# Looping a section of Javascript a set number of time

Tags: javascript, loops

What do I add at the beginning and end of a section of code to repeat it 36 times before going on?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **[loop statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Loop_Statements)**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 36; i++ ) {
    // This will loop 36 times
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You add a for loop:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `for` loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for